# Family Tree styling using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google's Visualization: Organizational Chart library,

Link to documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

I'm trying to change the  style and create links for each node.

I've been trying to use: 
`chart.setRowProperty((nodenumber), 'style', 'background-color:#FFF');`
for each node but unsuccessfully. Wherever I place that code just crashes the script. Any idea why? What would be the best way to create links from each independent node?

**Javascript:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['orgchart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'parent');
    data.addColumn('string', 'hover');
    data.addRows([
      ['Parent', '', ''],
      ['Kid1', 'Parent', ''],
      ['Kid2', 'Parent', ''],
      ['GreatKid3', 'Kid1', ''],
      ['GreatKid4', 'Kid1', ''],
      ['GreatKid5', 'Kid2', ''],
      ['GreatGreatKid6', 'GreatKid5', ''],
      ['GreatGreatKid7', 'GreatKid5', ''],

    ]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse:true});
    chart.collapse(1,true);
    chart.collapse(2,true);
  }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#chart_div{
    width:800px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Try running it here https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#org_chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes the script because the OrgChart object does not have a #setRowProperty method - you want to use the DataTable#setRowProperty method:

```
data.setRowProperty((nodenumber), 'style', 'background-color:#FFF');
```

Also, setting the "background-color" style on the node won't do what you want, as there is a "background" style that will override it, so you have to set "background:#FFF" to actually get the background color to show.  Here's an example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/YZ7CB/

Comment: What would be the best way to create links from the nodes to another page? Would it be to create some sort of select event for each node or is there an easier method?

Comment: I managed to create links by creating divs within the nodes:[{v:'Parent', f:'<div><a href="http://www.google.com"> Parent </a></div>'}, '', ''], fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZ7CB/3/   to anyone wondering why the formatting would look strange on <IE8 it is because it doesn't support 'inherit. '